# How to get Rails application working on two domains, Reverse Proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, cross-domain, reverse-proxy

I have two separate application running on `www.a.com` and `www.b.com`. The second one is a rails-3 application. To get some common login working between the two by sharing cookies, I am redirecting all requests on `www.a.com/b` to `www.b.com`. I am using apache reverse proxy to achieve this:

```
ProxyPass /b/ http://www.b.com/
```

This works fine apart from the fact that all the asset/javascript links are getting formed by assuming `www.a.com` to be the root. 
For example:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'js/bootstrap-datepicker'%>
```

is resulting in the link `http://a.com/assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js` whereas I want this to be `http://a.com/b/assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js`

I am solving this by doing:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://a.com/analytics"
```

This works fine even though I find the solution to be a bit hacky.
The real problem starts when I put links to other pages in my application. So in order to put a link to the page named `page`, I need to put `b/page` in my href. This works fine when I am accessing the application using a.com. But this doesn't allow me to access the app using b.com as the link starts pointing to `www.b.com/b/page` which obviously doesn't exist.

How can I get the whole thing working so that I can access my application using either a.com or b.com.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution to your problem, use sub-domain and CNAME/ALIAS instead of reverse proxy.

Instead of reverse proxying a.com/b to b.com. You point new.a.com to the application running at b.com using CNAME/ALIAS in DNS.

Set cookie domain as a.com instead of www.a.com, so that cookies are shared across subdomains.

config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
YouApplicationName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'some_key', :domain => ".a.com"
```